# Object result from a left join is null c#

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to do a left join in Linq joining two different list as you can see below:

```
var fab = (from a in lstt
           join b in lstt2 on new { a.PO, a.Line } equals new { b.PO, b.Line } into newab
           from ab in newab.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new BomFabConcentrado
           {
             PO = a.PO,
             Line = a.Line,
             Fabric1 = ab.Fabric1
            }).ToList();
```

The problem is that the result of ab is null and I got the following error message:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> ab was null.

As extra information lstt contains 900 elements and lstt contains 200.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: The whole point of a left join is to end up with a result element even if the join doesn't match anything on the right side - which is why you're using `DefaultIfEmpty()`. So you should absolutely be expecting that `ab` might be null... otherwise you could just use an equijoin. Presumably `lstt` contains some entry with no corresponding entry in `lstt2`.

Comment: Use `ab?.Fabric1`

Comment: Sorry, I new here and I don't know how to mark you answer as the solution, but this is the one that works

Answer (score 0):

Left join use following query

```
var fab = (from a in lstt
        join b in lstt2 on new { a.PO, a.Line } equals new { b.PO, b.Line } into newab
        from ab in newab.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new BomFabConcentrado
        {
          PO = a.PO,
          Line = a.Line,
          Fabric1 = (ab == null || ab.Fabric1 == null) ? 0 : ab.Fabric1
          //or use
          Fabric1 = ab?.Fabric1 ?? 0
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this and its work but as inner join, is there a way to do it as a left join?                                       thanks

Comment: That left join code is still susceptible to NullReferenceException problems....

Comment: @JonSkeet I code to (ab == null || ab.Fabric1 == null)? 0: ab.Fabric1 changed so that null records do not cause errors. it now works

Comment: @AAM  i edited answer . this work . test it

Comment: @MeysamAsadi: Right - although `ab?.Fabric1 ?? 0` would be a better way of writing that, IMO.

Answer (score -1):

Add a null check to your lists. For example like this:

```
    lstt = lstt.Where(a => a != null).ToList();
    lstt2 = lstt2.Where(b => b != null).ToList();


    var fab = (from a in lstt
           join b in lstt2 on new { a.PO, a.Line } equals new { b.PO, b.Line } 
           into newab
           from ab in newab.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new BomFabConcentrado
           {
             PO = a.PO,
             Line = a.Line,
             Fabric1 = ab.Fabric1
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Whether or not the source lists contain any `null` elements has nothing to do with the result of the `join` containing some `null` elements.